# setRefreshed: unrecognized selector sent to UIViewController in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector

I have multiple UITableviewControllers which support landscape mode and one UIViewController which does not support landscape mode.  Regardless of which view is showing, when I close the app while in landscape mode I get the following exception:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LedgerViewController setRefreshed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x161df0'

Closing the app in portrait mode does not generate the exception.

A full search of my project does not find the term "setRefreshed" nor can I find the term in any Apple documentation or via Google.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found that adding the following code to each view controller stopped the exception from firing:
`-(void) setRefreshed: (BOOL) refreshed {}`

How can I figure out what is calling "setRefreshed:"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks to the AWESOME people at raywenderlich.com who take the time to write some of the best tutorials available:  [My App Crashed, Now What? – Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

An exception breakpoint led me to some poor code in my ApplicationDelegate which assumed the navingationController's rootViewController was "RootViewController" which has a BOOL property of "refreshed".  That was a good assumption until I implemented a different view for landscape mode.  Hence the reason why the exception was only thrown in landscape mode.

#### Things I learned today:

1. With KVC, it should have been obvious to me that "setRefreshed" is the KVC equivalent to "????.refreshed".
2. I should have read up on advanced debugging techniques years ago.